# How to prevent "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos" when using np.where()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

I have a Series of floats that also contains some NaNs. I need to perform an arccos on these floats so I use:

`out = np.where((in >= -1) & (in <= 1), (np.arccos(in) * 180) / np.pi, np.nan)`

to make sure I'm only selecting values within the acceptable arccos range of [-1, 1]. However, I'm still getting this warning when doing so:

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos`.

I believe this is because the arccos is getting NaN values still. How can I prevent this from happening? Shouldn't the `(in >= -1) & (in <= 1)` condition remove all NaNs?

Comment: That is because np.arccos(in) is computed **before** np.where. Try  np.arccos(np.clip(in, -1,1))

Comment: In Python, the arguments of a function such as `np.where` are evaluated before being passed in.  `np.arccos` has its own `where` parameter (you want to supply an `out` as well).